# import output of command instead of a file - python

Tags: python, import

I have a very simple script that i wish to test out.

Master script (caller.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import test2
test2.printMe()
```

Function/Module Script (test2.py):

```
def printMe():
    print 'this actually works'
```

When I run caller.py, it works.  Because the test2.py script exists in the same directory from which I'm calling caller.py.

What happens if i need to make the function(s) defined in test2.py available to the caller.py script, through a variable?  There are times when the content of the test2.py function script wont always be in a file.  Sometimes, it's inside a variable.

So basically, im looking for a way to access the functions that are in a variable just as import would access functions that are in a file.

I wish to be able to do something like this:

```
from commands import *

def run_command(cmd):
    status, text = getstatusoutput(cmd)
    print text

run_command('python /tmp/test2.py')
test2.printMe()
```

Please advise.

Comment: Have a look at [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__).

Comment: i've been struggling with this for a while. any real life examples you can provide please?

Comment: What on earth? What does "the content of test2.py is sometimes inside a variable" mean? Does that mean you have a gigantic string that contains python code? Does it mean you have a string like `"python /tmp/test2.py"`? In both cases, __why__? Where does that variable come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from sys import path as sys_path
from os import path

def import_module(path_to_py_file):
    dir_name, module_name = path.split(path.splitext(path_to_py_file)[0])
    sys_path.append(dir_name)
    return __import__(module_name)
```

Now you can do this:

```
test2 = import_module(r'/tmp/test2.py')
test2.printMe()
```

Comment: can i do something like:  test2 = import_module('cat /tmp/test2.py')